# Can the @3x assets for iPhone 6 plus have odd pixels? i.e. 248 x 171px

Tags: ios, iphone, assets, pixel

I think previously for @2x it was not suggested to use assets with odd pixels. How about now with the @3x assets? When I increased the resolution for my @2x assets, most of them came out with odd pixels. 
example: 128 x 88 px --> 248 x 171 px, 
         580 x 80 px -->1125 x 156 px

Comment: Did you try it? Did you have any issues?

Comment: Seems natural that this would happen now. I suppose what you don't want now are assets with pixels that don't divide evenly by three.

Comment: BTW - If your 1x image is 128x88, your 3x image needs to be 384x264. How did you come up with 248x171? If your 2x image is 128x88 then your 3x image would need to be 192x132, not 248x171.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points to consider.

1. If a 1x image has an odd number of pixels then the 2x image won't since 2 times any number (even or odd) is an even number. So all 2x images end up having an even number of pixels. But a 3x image doesn't follow that rule. If the 1x image has odd pixels, then so will the 3x image. If the 1x image has even pixels then so will the 2x and 3x images.
2. Your math is off. You seem to be upscaling your images by 1.95 which make no sense. Either triple your 1x images or scale up your 2x images by 1.5, not 1.95.

This means your 128x88 2x image will be a 192x132 3x image, not 248x171.

There is no reason why 3x images can't have an odd pixel dimension. Why would it be a problem?

Comment: I see... example: at 1x 290x40 -> 2x 580x80-> 3x 1125x156 px. I got confused because I based it on when I upscaled 640x1136 pixels to  1242 x 2208 (x1.94).. I used a script to do the same to the rest of the 2x assets, by increasing the resolution. I got carried away with the mocks.. It made the new assets also fit the new 1242x2208 px mocks.  Well, I will just increase all assets literally by 3x (duh... silly me) Thank you very much for the information!!   1x 290x40 -> 2x 580x80-> 3x 870x120 px

Comment: oh and I was uncertain about the odd pixels because as the person who cuts assets, in the past I was told to make sure they are even pixels. I wasn't sure if the reasoning still applied to 3x assets.